# Promising someone Paradise

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come, martyr, masecheth-avodah-zarah

In [Avoda Zarah 18a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=18&format=text):

> The Executioner then said to him (Rabbi Chanina ben Tradyon), 'Rabbi,
>   if I raise the flame and take away the tufts of wool from over your
>   heart, will you bring me into the world to come?' 'Yes,' he
>   replied. 'Then swear unto me' [he urged]. He swore unto him. He
>   thereupon raised the flame and removed the tufts of wool from over his
>   heart, and his soul departed speedily. The Executioner then jumped and
>   threw himself into the fire.

How could Rabbi Chanina ben Tradyon promise someone Olam Haba and furthermore with an oath?

Comment: Is this more difficult than any other statement anywhere in Chazal which states who will and who will not merit entry to the world to come?

Comment: @mevaqesh yes..

Comment: Perhaps clarify why in your question.

Comment: @mevaqesh  dont see why it should be the same. here was a personal request rather than a general rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44813/discussion-between-mevaqesh-and-ray).

Comment: A bigger question is how he got Olam Haba when his last unregretted acts were murder and suicide.

Comment: Forecast, not promise. R Chanina ben Teradyon said that based on his knowledge about what earns olam haba, he believes that the centurion would indeed make it to olam haba -- qoneh olamo besha'ah achas.

Comment: @MichaBerger Yes that was my point, as I indicated here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32062918#32062918

Comment: @Yishai the quickening of death to alleviate suffering may be permissible for a nonjew. At least that's what Reb Moshe entertained in a teshuva. And his suicide would have been to prevent his own suffering by torture so these may not be sins.